# Customise UISearchBar design programatically

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, uikit, uisearchbar

can anybody help me build this kind of SearchBar on with his own class ? mine looks like this , how can I make image bigger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enI5n.png)
that's what I want to achieve
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvDZC.png)

```
    class SearchBar: UISearchBar {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.frame = frame
        
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        self.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.showsBookmarkButton = false
        self.showsCancelButton = false
        self.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
        
        
        
        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        let glassIconView = textFieldInsideSearchBar?.leftView as? UIImageView
        glassIconView?.image = glassIconView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        glassIconView?.backgroundColor = .red
        
        
    }
    

    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: For native searchbar You cannot customise it. For customizatio0n you have to create your own searchbar using
 Textfield.

Comment: so is it good idea to make UiView where it will be textfield and image(for search icon) and than I need to connect it to my custom UISearchController(which I have no idea how ;d ) and than to use it on my ViewController

Comment: Yeah Go ahead..